How do I export FireStore database to Google Sheets automatically?
I need to export FireStore database to Google Sheets automatically for my project.
there is my Apps Script function.
function exportFirestoreToSheets() {
  // Connect to Firestore
  
  const email = "###.gserviceaccount.com";
  const key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----###\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  const projectId = "moked-report";

  const firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("moked reports data"); // Change this to your desired sheet name
  // If the sheet doesn't exist, create it
  if (!sheet) {
    sheet = ss.insertSheet("moked reports data");
  }

  const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("reports");
  
  allDocuments.forEach((doc, index) => {
    const data = doc.fields; // Assuming the document structure is represented as fields
    const rowData = Object.values(data);
    // Write data to the next available row in the sheet
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
  });
}


I get "Execution completed" but I don't see a Google Sheets file with the data.
I debugged the function, the function gets the data from the collection but Google Sheets file is't created.
Thanks in advance.
rowData
allDocuments pic

Can you provide your sample value of allDocuments and rowData? I'm worried that allDocuments or rowData might be empty. By the way, I removed your private key and email of the service account from your question.

I added a picture, thanks.

It's better to add textual data as text as they're easy to copy/paste. For eg, console.log(rowData) would give the data as text.

allDocuments - Info [ { name: 'projects/moked-reports/databases/(default)/documents/reports/3QMFQlZcpgpSKKL3tExC',
fields:
{ date: [Object],
'machine name': [Object],
'reason for stop': [Object],
'worker name': [Object],
status: [Object] },
createTime: '2024-04-23T08:13:43.660107Z',
updateTime: '2024-04-23T08:13:43.660107Z',
readTime: '2024-04-27T13:06:04.371477Z' },

rowData - Info [ { timestampValue: '2024-04-23T08:13:42.382Z' },
{ stringValue: 'V414' },
{ stringValue: 'חלק מביקורת' },
{ stringValue: 'eyal' },
{ stringValue: 'working' } ]

Turn it into a two dimensional array and use setValues()

Thank you for replying. From your reply comments, I proposed a modified script. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, please put a script console.log(JSON.stringify(allDocuments)) just after the line of const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("reports"); and run the script. And, please provide the values of log console.log(JSON.stringify(allDocuments)). By this, I would like to modify the script.

From your following comments,

allDocuments - Info [ { name: 'projects/moked-reports/databases/(default)/documents/reports/3QMFQlZcpgpSKKL3tExC', fields: { date: [Object], 'machine name': [Object], 'reason for stop': [Object], 'worker name': [Object], status: [Object] }, createTime: '2024-04-23T08:13:43.660107Z', updateTime: '2024-04-23T08:13:43.660107Z', readTime: '2024-04-27T13:06:04.371477Z' },


rowData - Info [ { timestampValue: '2024-04-23T08:13:42.382Z' }, { stringValue: 'V414' }, { stringValue: 'חלק מביקורת' }, { stringValue: 'eyal' }, { stringValue: 'working' } ]

From these comments, I guessed that allDocuments[0].fields might be as follows.
{
  "date": { "timestampValue": "2024-04-23T08:13:42.382Z" },
  "machine name": { "stringValue": "V414" },
  "reason for stop": { "stringValue": "חלק מביקורת" },
  "worker name": { "stringValue": "eyal" },
  "status": { "stringValue": "working" }
}

In your showing script, rowData of sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]); is [{"timestampValue":"2024-04-23T08:13:42.382Z"},{"stringValue":"V414"},{"stringValue":"חלק מביקורת"},{"stringValue":"eyal"},{"stringValue":"working"}]. So, when this is run, these values are put into the 1st row of "moked reports data" sheet. At least, the values are put into cells. But you say I get "Execution completed" but I don't see a Google Sheets file with the data.. In this case, I'm worried that your actual values might be different from your situation.
From this situation, by believing the values of allDocuments and rowData in your comments, I propose a modified script. The modified script using your provided values of allDocuments and rowData is as follows.
Modified script:
function exportFirestoreToSheets() {
  // Connect to Firestore
  
  const email = "###.gserviceaccount.com";
  const key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----###\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  const projectId = "moked-report";

  const firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("moked reports data"); // Change this to your desired sheet name
  // If the sheet doesn't exist, create it
  if (!sheet) {
    sheet = ss.insertSheet("moked reports data");
  }

  const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("reports");
  
  // I modified the below script.
  const keys = Object.keys(allDocuments[0].fields);
  const values = allDocuments.map((doc) => keys.map(k => Object.values(doc.fields[k])[0]));
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}


In this modification, a 2-dimensional array is created from fields of allDocuments, and the array is put into cells.

Note:

I proposed this modified script by believing that your provided values are correct values. If this modified script didn't work, can you provide the values of allDocuments again? At that time, please put a script console.log(JSON.stringify(allDocuments)) just after the line of const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("reports"); and run the script. And, please provide the values of log console.log(JSON.stringify(allDocuments)). By this, I would like to modify the script.

